# How to get data from js & Reactjs using beautifulsoup?

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am doing web Crawling in using beautiful.I get the Data from various websites but i am not getting from some of website i find that these website show data using js.

I write the following script to derived data and it works fine but not in some which is usind JS for their data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib2

params = {"url":"search-alias=aps","field-keywords":"j7"}
url = "http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=params).content)
ul = soup.findAll("h2" ,{"class":"a-size-medium a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal"})
j=0
for a in ul:
   print a.contents
   print "\n"
   j=j+1
```

It works fine in that but some website is there they are using js to fetch data and show data so i cant get data by that way

Comment: I'm confused... is this JS or Python?

Comment: It is python . But i am asking that there is some website who call js and display data so i cant get it by this code

Comment: wouldn't you need to parse the JS? I think you'd have to specify that when calling `BeautifulSoup()`

Comment: I want the data after called js. now i am getting the data but before calling js so some data is missed.@DrewDavis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nature of the web is client-server: the server delivers content to the web site, and the browser displays it. This may include client-side scripting, which is JavaScript code that the browser executes, which may modify the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

So, in order to pic up the modified DOM, any client (this includes your Python code) would have to create a DOM from the HTML and then execute the JavaScript to modify the DOM as the browser would have.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python) might give you some clues. Sadly since I have now noticed that answer it means this question should really be closed.